# C# Combine methods by passing in field type?

Tags: c#, methods

I wasn't sure how to title this question correctly but here is what i'm trying to do.

Say I have a class Customer that has an ID, firstName, and lastName field.  Now say I have a list of customers and I want to write one method that will write ID, firstName, OR lastName to the console depending on which one I specify.

In essense, I would like to write one method that accepts the field I would like to print out instead of writing three seperate methods to print out each field type.

I know I have read about how to do this in C# over the past few days but my brain is on overload and it is slipping my mind....

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

```
public void PrintCustomer<T>(Customer c, Func<Customer, T> func)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", c.ID, func(c));
}
```

Usage:

```
PrintCustomer(myCustomer, c => c.FirstName);
```

OR

```
PrintCustomer(myCustomer, c => c.LastName);
```

Comment: I added what I consider to be an improvement on this solution in another answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use an Enum as an argument?  Each enum value is a different target field...

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a comment on BFree's answer but I wanted to have syntax highlighting...

The type of the return value can be hidden from client code using the following signature. I would consider this an improvement.

```
public static void PrintCustomer(Customer c, Func<Customer, string> func)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} , {1}", c.ID, func(c));
}
```

Comment: Then don't you have to type "PrintCustomer(myCustomer, c => c.ID.ToString());" instead of "PrintCustomer(myCustomer, c => c.ID);"  if Customer.ID is an integer?